# Java Pair vs HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

A Java Pair has a key and a value but only stores one record.

HashMap records are also comprised of keys and values but the HashMap can store more than one record.

When to use pair over a hashmap with one record? What is the purpose of Java Pairs? The only advantage of pairs that I see is that it explicitly only allows one record per pair.

Comment: Are you asking about [javafx.Pair<A, B>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/util/Pair.html)? since java util does not have `Pair<A, B>`? Java has [`SimpleEntry<A, B>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) which is similar to `Pair`. Like you said `Pair` represents one record versus `Map` is a multiple `Pairs`.

Comment: Using the correct type for the job is important. It self-documents the code, makes the code more readable, and forces developers to use the code correctly. It's the same reason you'd create a `Person` class with named properties instead of using a `List` per person storing each property at some arbitrary index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sort of like asking *"Why have an object when you can have a List of one object"*... A `HashMap` is a data structure which usually has to allocate more memory than is used by the objects it stores. I really can't see any good reason to create a `HashMap` of one object. If you're going to have just one object, then just have that object.. don't needlessly put it in a more complicated data structure..

Comment: Keeping things simple is a good rule of thumb. To bring it to a real world analogy, a hash with a single key value pair is like delivering a single egg in a carton designed for 12 eggs. What's the point of including all that overhead when you never use it? Now you have to deal with waste, added expense, balance, etc. for no additional benefit.

Comment: @xtratic thanks for the answers, good explanations. What if I extended this logic and said "If you're going to have just two objects, then just have two objects" or hashmap with size limited to 2? Why does java have a completely different pair type rather than having built in size restriction for hashmap? Not challenging their design decisions, just want to grow as a developer and understand.

Comment: @Index Even with a size-restricted `Map` the API still provides methods which encourage doing something that will break the code. A `Pair`, or any other kind of tuple class, has exactly the API it needs to support what it does. Such classes are typically immutable as well. Also, you have to be careful with interfaces which allow arbitrary restrictions to be applied by implementations; it may or may not break the _Liskov substitution principle_ and/or the _principle of least surprise_. Java's _Collection Framework_ already has an abundance of "optional" methods.